# Could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, redux, module, react-redux, create-react-app

I'm trying to do my exportable package in which I create the redux store. This is the code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { ErrorPage } from "../components/shared";
import { MyCoreApplication } from "./MyCoreApplication";
import { configureStore } from "../tools/configureStore";
import { createCoreHelp } from "./createCoreHelp";

export const MyCore = ({ withLogs, applicationSagas, applicationReducers, app, cookieInfo }) => {
  const help = createCoreHelp(applicationSagas, applicationReducers, app);
  if (help.error) return <ErrorPage errorMessage={help.error} tooltipMessage={help.tooltip} />;
  else {
    const store = configureStore(withLogs, applicationSagas, applicationReducers);
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MyCoreApplication app={app} cookieInfo={cookieInfo} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
};
```

MyCoreApplication is the same:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { CookieBar, ErrorPage, LoadingSpinner, Notification } from "../components/shared";
import { getConfig, getConfigStore, fetchConfigEnded, isMobileMode, setMobileMode } from "../modules/configuration";
import { getLocale, setLocale, getMessages, fetchMessages } from "../modules/language";

export const MyCoreApplication = ({ app, cookieInfo }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const config = useSelector(getConfigStore);
  const configLoaded = useSelector(fetchConfigEnded);
  const mobileMode = useSelector(isMobileMode);
  const messages = useSelector(getMessages);
  const locale = useSelector(getLocale);

  const actions = {
    getConfig: () => dispatch(getConfig()),
    setLocale: (locale) => dispatch(setLocale(locale)),
    fetchMessages: (locale) => dispatch(fetchMessages(locale)),
    setMobileMode: (checkMobile) => dispatch(setMobileMode(checkMobile)),
  };

  if (config === null && !configLoaded) dispatch(getConfig());
  else {
    if (!locale && config) actions.setLocale(config.defaultLanguage);
  }

  return config ? (
    <IntlProvider messages={messages} locale={locale} defaultLocale={config.defaultLanguage}>
      <Notification />
      <Router>{app}</Router>
      {cookieInfo && cookieInfo.useCookie && cookieInfo.infoLink && <CookieBar infoLink={cookieInfo.infoLink} />}
    </IntlProvider>
  ) : configLoaded ? (
    <ErrorPage />
  ) : (
    <LoadingSpinner />
  );
};
```

The goal of my package is to build a library which create redux store receiving sagas and reducer from the custom application. In this mode a developer who use this library hasn't to create the store because module has already done.
In this project I use webpack and after run build and pack npm commands I've got a .tgz file that I use in a create-react-app project as a dependency. In this create-react-app project I use my package in the following mode:

```js
import React from "react-dom";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { MyCore } from "my_core";
import { appSagas } from "./store/appSagas";
import { appReducers } from "./store/appReducers";
import { App } from "./container/App";
import "./styles/index.scss";

const wrapper = document.getElementById("container");
wrapper &&
  ReactDOM.render(
    <MyCore
      withLogs={true}
      applicationSagas={appSagas}
      applicationReducers={appReducers}
      app={<App />}
    />,
    wrapper
  );
```

And this is the App code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Layout } from "antd";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { MyHeader as Header } from "../components/MyHeader.jsx";
import { Components } from "my_core";

const { MyFooter: Footer } = Components;

const { Content } = Layout;

export const App = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Content>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            hello
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Content>
    </Router>
  </Layout>
);
```

Finally, inside MyHeader I use useSelector as the following code shows:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Utility } from "my_core";

const { configUtils } = Utility;

export const MyHeader = () => {
  const mobileMode = useSelector(configUtils.isMobileMode);

  return mobileMode ? <div>Mobile Header</div> : <div>Desktop Header</div>;
};
```

When I start the create-react-app project I encounter this error:

```
useSelector() Error: Could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

The same identical code, if written inside MyCore package project, works fine.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You get jsx result from App before wrapping it in Provider and then try to put the resulting jsx in MyCore but there would already be an error because `app={<App />}` is not in a Provider.

Comment: @HMR Can you kindly explain it with a simple example please?

Comment: Don't pass `{app={<App />}}` and in MyCoreApplication do `<Router><App /></Router>` not sure if that would break createCoreHelp but I have no idea what that's for.

Comment: @HMR if I don't pass `app={<App />}` I can't see the content of my custom Application. MyCore library is only a wrapper that builds the store and export some utility and components. Path logics and all the visualization layout is inside the `<App />` components of the custom application which has MyCore installed as a dependency.
Ignore createCoreHelp because it is useful only to show a error message if some parameters are wrong

Comment: In that case you have to do this `app={<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>}`

Comment: @HMR in my custom application I have not a store. That is configured inside myCore module. 
In myCore module there's the creation of the redux store.
In custom application instead there's the app behaviour without store creation. Eventually sagas and reducer are passed to myCore as parameters

Comment: @HMR here https://github.com/iBobo5/myCore.git you can find myCore project.
It's enough to run npm install and npm run export to obtain .tgz file. Once it has been created copy in a create-react-app "test" project and install it with react and react-dom dependencies. Other dependencies are installed by the library.
Inside "test" project try to replace the import as shown above and inside a component use useSelector or useDispatch. In this way you could be able to reproduce my issue

Comment: I can't fix this. it is chicken and egg. You need to wrap App in Provider to pass it's jsx to MyCoreApplication but can't because MyCoreApplication also uses react-redux hooks and needs to be wrapped in Provider as well. Not sure why it matters so much where you call configureStore to you and insist on calling it in a place where you can't. Simplest would be to create the store where you do `ReactDOM.render`, wrap MyCore in a Provider and forget about passing app. Whenever I see jsx being passed as props or saved in state I wonder why this bad design is needed.

Answer (score 0):

At this link [github.com/iBobo5/myCore.git](https://github.com/iBobo5/myCore.git) you can find myCore project. It's enough to run npm install and npm run export to obtain .tgz file. Once it has been created copy in a create-react-app "test" project and install it with react and react-dom dependencies. Other dependencies are installed by the library. Inside "test" project try to replace the import as shown above and inside a component use useSelector or useDispatch. In this way you could be able to reproduce my issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you have react-redux as a dependency rather than a peerDependency in your package.json. So you will potentially have two versions in the application in which the library is consumed, which causes the bug you described.